# When can matrices be extended to a non-singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have $n$ square matrices $M_{1},...,M_{n}$, call $M'$ an extension if it is a square matrix of the form 
$$M'=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
M_{1} & A\\
B & M_{2}\\
 &  & \ddots\\
 &  &  & M_{n} & X\\
 &  &  & Y & Z
\end{array}\right)$$
Is there always a non-singular extension for $n$ square matrices regardless of whether they are themselves non-singular? For $n=1$ this is indeed true, since we have 
$$M'=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
M & I\\
I & 0
\end{array}\right)
 $$
with inverse 
$$M'^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & I\\
I & -M
\end{array}\right)
 $$

Comment: Are the unwritten entries necessarily zero?

Comment: In other words: is $M'$ supposed to be block-[tridiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)?

Comment: No, the unwritten entries can be anything, not tridiagonal.

Comment: Do you care about the size of the blocks?

Comment: Only requirement is that the matrices $M_{1},...,M_{n}$ appear as blocks on the diagonal, the off diagonal blocks can be anything.

Comment: don't care about the size of blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be any extension of $M_1,M_2,\dots,M_n$.  If we choose an invertible extension $M'$ of $M$, then $M'$ is also an invertible extension of $M_1,M_2,\dots,M_n$.